# Get column value onclick HTML table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have this html table:

tabela

```
   |A|B|C|D|
   _________
001|M|N|O|P|
002|R|S|T|U|
```

And with this script I can get the row 1st value, e. onclick N get the value 001

```
var table = document.getElementById("tabela");
var rows = table.rows;
for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].onclick = (function() {
        var rowid = (this.cells[0].innerHTML); 
        window.location.href = "next.php?rowidphp="+ rowid;
               });
            }
```

The thing is that I need to get the column 1st value, e. onclick N shuld get the value B

I'm trying everything but I can reach the point.....

Comment: Please provide [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: What will be clicked and what value you want? I am not clear on what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t7G6K/

```
var table = document.getElementById("tabela");
var rows = table.rows;
for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].onclick = (function (e) {
        var rowid = (this.cells[0].innerHTML);
        var j = 0;
        var td = e.target;
        while( (td = td.previousElementSibling) != null ) 
            j++;
        alert(rows[0].cells[j].innerHTML);
    });
}
```

Comment: This is just a simple example, however. It's not cross browser. I guarantee only modern browsers.

Comment: when i can. the +1 is granted

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
table = document.getElementById("tablea");
var rows = table.rows;
for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].cells[2].onclick = function (e) {
        rowid = e.target.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.textContent;
        alert(rowid);
    };
}
```

Here is the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b7kv7/)**

Comment: this is what I have in other aplications, find the row..... I need to find the column

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2dAkj/9/#

Ok with jQuery i would do it like this.

```
$(function () {
    $('table').on('click', function (e) {
        var x = $(e.target);
        var index = x.parents('tr').find('td,th').index(x);
        alert($(x.parents('table').find('tr').first().find('td,th')[index]).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: works just like the 1st ansewer, tks. the +1 is granted when I get the reputation to that.